# What do the /X.XX refer to on the pin naming in this schematic

Tags: fpga, schematics

I was looking at [this](https://cdn.alchitry.com/docs/alchitry_au_sch.pdf) development board from Alchitry and the schematic has the pin names written as in the picture below. I can't figure out what exactly the bit after the forward slash are referring to for instance L5/2.2E, what is the 2.2E referring to.

[image]

Comment: What kind of package is the FPGA?  My guess is that it's some sort of BGA/PGA, and this is the tool vendor's way of specifying the ring (or ring segment) and the specific pin.  Or maybe a row/column designation.

Comment: Moments later, turns out its the FPGA package (I got that bit), then /page.columnrow of the schematic referring to where the other end of the pin is connected in the schematic. Must be an Eagle thing. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, off page connections!  Makes sense.  Should have guessed that :-(

Comment: Yes, those are off page references. Eagle decided that they should be part of the tag; other CAD programs add these separately, alongside the tag. I dislike the Eagle way as it obfuscates the actual net name.

Comment: `2.2E` means page 2, coordinate 2E